# Linking glib in XCode

Tags: xcode, linker, shared-libraries, glib, quartz-composer

I have a strange issue, that may be obvious, but is really not clear for me at the moment :

I'm making a Quartz Composer plugin.
I have an XCode workspace based which includes a custom library. This library is compiling the poly2tri-c delaunay triangulation library, which is **linking against glib**. 
I have no trouble with compiling my library, but the plugin itself doesn't want to compile and throw these errors :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "p2t_cdt_new(_GPtrArray*)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "p2t_cdt_free(CDT_*)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "p2t_point_new_dd(double, double)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "p2t_cdt_triangulate(CDT_*)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "p2t_cdt_get_triangles(CDT_*)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "p2t_triangle_get_point(_P2tTriangle*, int)", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "_g_ptr_array_add", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>     "_g_ptr_array_new", referenced from:
>         -[hOzPolygon2D triangulationWithRefineSteps:holes:steinerPoints:] in libhOzVector.a(hOzPolygons.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is the pic of the compiler messages :

[image: Compiler messages]

And of my links :

[image: Links]

I usually have these messages when I forget to link against a lib, but here I'm linking against glib in the library itself and in the plugin project.

Any ideas on what's wrong ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some "esoteric" research, I finally found what was wrong : XCode was just **not automatically including the c files in the target membership**...

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm having a similar problem. I include the -I arguments in XCode's Other C Flags section, and If I create for example a GList pointer, I have no problem, but the compiler throws an error if I call any GLib function, such as g_list_append()

Comment: I don't know what's happening for you exactly. But, for me, it was only that all my projects files wren't with the .mm extension ; and, the GLib source files weren't added automatically in the Target Membership (right XCode panel).